# New To Ubuntu; Have Reboot issues after Updates

Tags: updates, laptop, asus, reboot

I am new to Linux. I wiped my ASUS laptop and installed Ubuntu. I tried to search for my issue, but I hadn't come across what I needed. Things work well and I am enjoying using Linux. However, when I run updates and have to reboot, I have a problem. I get a blinking cursor and can't get to the GUI. Unplugging power and pulling out my battery and re-installing the battery seems to fix the issue.

Would anyone know what the problem could be without resulting to this technique? I don't even see the ASUS load screen. It reboots a blinking cursor and I can do nothing.

I feel like a fish in a big big pond. Appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you fully shut down instead of reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal in Recovery Mode and try to update the manager using the below command. After doing so try to boot the GUI.

```
 sudo update-manager -d
```

Hope this will help you to fix the issue.